# Are these dents repairable using hot water and a plunger?

Tags: repair, dent

I'm looking at buying a car that has a couple dents in it because of its low price. The dents don't look too bad so I'm wondering if anyone with experience of fixing dents at home thinks that they're repairable using the plunger and hot water method? I'm guessing either the person selling the car hasn't heard of the method or the dents are irreparable. Thanks in advance! [image: dent 1][image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A big dimple maybe, a small one unlikely. Not a toilet plunger I hope

Comment: You might be able to slide your hand behind the shroud and press it out from the inside.

Comment: if there is no sharp bends in the metal you can use a vacuum to get it back to shape.in the two dents on your car there is sharp edges so you can not pull out the dents yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dent looks too big for a"plunger" repair. I think the plunger method is more for hail dents which would be much smaller ( hopefully). Hail dents I have had are more like 10 to 20% the size of the dent in the second photo. I have heard of fixing hail dents with ice in hot weather but not hot water. However, it is probably worth a try because a body shop will be expensive. As commented , it looks more like a "push from the back" job.